# Is it wise to pthead_join() class member-variable thread in the destructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I need to make a thread that should run for the duration of the time a class exists.  The thread should be destroyed with the class.  Would it be wise to code with this general design (join in destructor)?  Should I use a detached thread instead possibly?

```
class A {
    public:
        A()  { pthread_create(m_thread, ...); }
        ~A() { pthread_join(m_thread, ...);   }

    private:
        pthread_t m_thrad;
};
```

Lastly, can I use a member function to spawn off the thread, or does it have to be a static or global function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you access data from your class A from within the thread then you must join it in the destructor. A detached thread would otherwise access the class data after it has been destroyed which is simply undefined behavior.

Your thread function must be static or global. But you can pass your class' this pointer as arg parameter to pthread_create and static_cast it back in your thread main function and call a normal method on your class. So you have a very slim static function:

```
class X {
  public:
    X() {
      pthread_create(m_thread, 0, ThreadStart, this);
    }
  private:
    static void *ThreadStart(void *arg) {
      static_cast<X *>(arg)->ThreadMain();
      return 0;
    }
    void ThreadMain() {
    }
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it depends on what is the `A` class about. If you know for sure that the thread will exit some time soon after your instance of the `A` class dies then I guess you could use detached threads. Otherwise I think you should signal the thread that it should exit and wait for it to do so.